# Tab completion in ipdb not working when output is processed

Tags: shell, autocomplete, pipe, ipython, ipdb

Sometimes I resort to using `ipdb` for debugging a Python script, which has a very nice autocomplete feature.

The problem is, the script usually runs through a shell pipeline that processes its output (for instance `python script.py |& tee "stdout.txt"`).

To me it seems like there is no answer to this (either live without autocomplete, or disable the `stdout` piping).

My question is made up of two parts:

- Is there any way to have both autocomplete and stdout processing?
- If not, exactly why not?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I worked around this by avoiding shell pipes, and writing the output file from Python itself.

I can watch the file change live using `less +F`.

I guess I was asking for too much interactivity from L/Unix pipes.